# Typescript - Repository and transactions

Tags: typescript

I want to separate my service layer in my typescript nodejs app from my data access layer, so that if we ever need to change the database from ArangoDB to something else we don't need to touch the service layer.
Also this helps in testing.

To do this, I am using a repository pattern (or similar).

- Each method in the repository takes as the last argument an optional transaction.
- Each repository has a 'special' method that the service layer calls to setup the transaction called `withTransaction`.

I want to be able to do the following in my service layer:

```
const transaction: RepoTransaction = await this.analysesRepository.withTransaction();
await this.analyzersRepository.withTransaction(transaction);
await transaction.start();
const analyzerData = await this.analyzersRepository.get(analyzerId, transaction);
await this.analysesRepository.create({ ... analyzer: analyzerData.name ... }, transaction);
await transaction.commit();
```

Where `RepoTransaction` in the first line is an interface not a concrete type.

Here are my types:

```
export interface TransactionableRepository {
    withTransaction(t?: RepoTransaction): Promise<RepoTransaction>;
}

export interface RepoTransaction {
    start(): Promise<void>;
    commit(): Promise<void>;
    abort(): Promise<void>;
}

export class ArangoDBTransaction implements RepoTransaction {
    private db: Database;
    private readConcerncs: AvailableCollections[];
    private writeConcerncs: AvailableCollections[];
    public transaction: Transaction; // <- arangodb transaction

    constructor(db: Database) {
        this.db = db;
        this.readConcerncs = [];
        this.writeConcerncs = [];
    }

    async start(): Promise<void> {
        this.transaction = await this.db.beginTransaction({
            read: this.readConcerncs,
            write: this.writeConcerncs
        });
    }

    async commit(): Promise<void> {
        await this.transaction.commit();
        if (this.db) this.db.close();
    }

    async abort(): Promise<void> {
        await this.transaction.abort();
        if (this.db) this.db.close();
    }

    async addWriteConcerns(...concerncs: AvailableCollections[]) {
        this.writeConcerncs.push(...concerncs);
    }

    async addReadConcerns(...concerncs: AvailableCollections[]) {
        this.readConcerncs.push(...concerncs);
    }
}
```

Example repository:

```
@Injectable()
export class AnalysisRepository implements TransactionableRepository {
    ...

    async withTransaction(t?: ArangoDBTransaction): Promise<ArangoDBTransaction> {
        if (t == undefined) {
            t = new ArangoDBTransaction(
                await this.dbHelperService.getDatabase(AvailableDatabases.RESULTS)
            );
        }
        t.addReadConcerns(
            AvailableCollections.ANALYSES,
            AvailableCollections.PROJECT_ANALYSES_EDGES
        );
        t.addWriteConcerns(
            AvailableCollections.ANALYSES,
            AvailableCollections.PROJECT_ANALYSES_EDGES
        );
        return t;
    }
    
   /**
     * Get an analysis
     * @param id Either _id or _key of the analysis
     * @throws {EntityNotFound} In case the analysis does not exist
     * @returns The analysis
     */
    async get(id: string, t?: ArangoDBTransaction): Promise<Analysis> {
    ...
        // If transaction is defined
        return await t.transaction.step(() => collection.document(id);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem with this is that the repository methods such as `withTransaction` `create` and `get` require the concrete type `ArangoDBTransaction` so they can access the database specific transaction object.
So in this code below, typescript rightfully complains (in the 2nd, 4rd and 5th line) that `RepoTransaction` does not implement all properties of `ArangoDBTransaction` when doing this:

```
const transaction: RepoTransaction = await this.analysesRepository.withTransaction();
await this.userRepository.withTransaction(transaction);
await transaction.start();
const analyzerData = await this.userRepository.get(userId, transaction);
await this.analysesRepository.create({ ... created_by: userId ... }, transaction);
await transaction.commit();
```

The problem is I want the service layer to stay agnostic to the Database used, so I cannot change line 1 to:

```
const transaction: ArangoDBTransaction = await this.analysesRepository.withTransaction();
```

because then each service needs to be modified upon a database change, whereas otherwise only the repositories need to be changed. Furthermore I want to hide specific methods from other developers by typing to `RepoTransaction`, so they cannot accidentally call a concrete method in the service layer.

The only cheap workaround I found is to change the repo methods so they use the interface `RepoTransaction`, like this with a `instanceof` check:

```
@Injectable()
export class AnalysisRepository implements TransactionableRepository {
    ...
    
    async withTransaction(T?: RepoTransaction): Promise<RepoTransaction> {
        if (T == undefined) {
            T = new ArangoDBTransaction(
                await this.dbHelperService.getDatabase(AvailableDatabases.RESULTS)
            );
        }
        if (T instanceof ArangoDBTransaction) {
            T.addReadConcerns(
                AvailableCollections.ANALYSES,
                AvailableCollections.PROJECT_ANALYSES_EDGES
            );
            T.addWriteConcerns(
                AvailableCollections.ANALYSES,
                AvailableCollections.PROJECT_ANALYSES_EDGES
            );
        }
        return T;
    }

   /**
     * Get an analysis
     * @param id Either _id or _key of the analysis
     * @throws {EntityNotFound} In case the analysis does not exist
     * @returns The analysis
     */
    async get(id: string, t?: RepoTransaction): Promise<Analysis> {
        if (t instanceof ArangoDBTransaction) {
            // Do the stuff here
        }
    }
```

However, I feel like the `instanceof` is a code smell and is a lot of boiler code that needs to be repeated in each method in the repository.

Is there a way to achieve the following:

- service layer does not program to concrete class but interface of the `RepoTransaction`
- Repositories use the concrete type in their methods, thus no need for cheap type checks or type casts.

Comment: Could it make sense to just rename `ArangoDBTransaction` class to something more generic like `RepositoryTransaction` and still have it implement the `RepoTransaction` interface? The only thing you should be swapping out in the case of a database change is the inner implementation of your existing `ArangoDBTransaction` class. Having a concrete class like `ArangoDBTransaction` extending a transaction interface seemingly only makes sense if you're planning to implement multiple databases within your app.

Comment: @Ben Indeed that makes sense. The only problem with that solution is that a developer might accidentally call a method of the `ArangoDBTransaction` (the concrete class) that is not part of the  `RepoTransaction` interface. Then, once we change the db, the service layer still needs to be changed (in case such a call was made). And since ts does not have a `package` modifier I cannot prevent developers from trying to call a method of the concrete class outside of the repositories folder.

That is why I would like it to be 'programmed to the interface' (terminology I know from Java development)